# Почему стили не применяются к wid_2?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

```
class Wid2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Wid2, self).__init__(parent)

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)

        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        wid.setStyleSheet('background:black;')
        wid.resize(500, 500)

        wid_2 = Wid2(self)
        wid_2.setStyleSheet('background:red;')
        wid_2.resize(500, 500)
```

Возможно я чего то не понимаю но разве `wid == wid_2`? Но тогда почему стили к нему не применились?

Comment: `background-color `

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Wid2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Wid2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = QLabel()
        layout = QGridLayout(self) 
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: #f0f;')

        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        wid.setStyleSheet('background: black;')
        wid.resize(400, 400)

        wid_2 = Wid2(self)  
        wid_2.setStyleSheet('background: red; border: 3px solid rgb(255, 205, 0);')
        wid_2.resize(300, 300)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]